# Sharepoint IF Statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

In my sharepoint list, I have a workflow that updates today date on a scheduler at 1 AM. When new records are generated Date 2(Create time stamp) is by default a later time than today date.

So as an example today may refresh at 1 AM and set the value to **2/6/2019 1:00 AM**. Later a record is created that populates Date 2 with **2/6/2019 2:45 PM**. When this formula is converted, it will display as a negative value.

```
=IF(Column1<>"",[Date1]-Date2,Today-Date2)
```

How can I change my if statement to say that when the value is 'negative' to just populate a blank value?

Answer (score 3):

The IF has 3 arguments, so:

IF(A, B, C)

- where A is a boolean expression
- B is what's returned if A is true
- and C is what's returned if A is false

So if you want a blank if the difference between the dates is negative, but otherwise the diff, then you want something like this:

```
=IF((Date-Created)>=0, Date-Created, "")
```

Which says if Date-Created is greater than or equal to 0, return Date-Created, otherwise return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

What's the data type of your Calculated Column?

This should always work:

```
=IF( IF(Column1<>"",[Date1]-Date2,Today-Date2) < 0, "", 
     IF(Column1<>"",[Date1]-Date2,Today-Date2) )
```

This is probably what you are looking for while testing Today vs. Date2:

```
=IF( Today-Date2 < 0, "", IF(Column1<>"",[Date1]-Date2,Today-Date2) )
```